# I want to import information retrieved from FirebaseAuth into a Text Widget and display it

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to import information retrieved from FirebaseAuth into a Text Widget and display it.

I'm new to Flutter and don't know much about it, so I'd like to know more.

By the way, I was able to get the information and display it in Print.

This is the code for the retrieving side.

```
void initState(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        String? name = user.displayName; // <-- User ID
        String? email = user.email; // <-- Their email
        String? image = user.photoURL;
        String? uid = user.uid;
        print(name);
        print(email);
        print(uid);
        print(image);
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the code for the side you want to display

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => account()),
              );
            },
            child:
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName:Text('name'),//I want it to appear here
              accountEmail: Text('email',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),//I want it to appear here
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1494938183448281089/xXIv3xmE_400x400.jpg',
                    width: 90,
                    height: 90,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1394312681209749510/1634787753/1500x500',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.event_available_outlined),
            title: Text('行事予定'),
            onTap: () {
              launch('https://www.ous.ac.jp/common/files//285/20220311164731084854.pdf');
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.public_outlined),
            title: Text('マイログ'),
            onTap: () {
              launchUrl(Uri.https('mylog.pub.ous.ac.jp', '/uprx/up/pk/pky501/Pky50101.xhtml'),mode:LaunchMode.externalApplication );

            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.book_outlined),
            title: Text('学生便覧'),
            onTap: () {
              launch('https://edu.career-tasu.jp/p/digital_pamph/frame.aspx?id=7540000-3-30&FL=0');
            },
          ),
          Divider(),

          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.link_outlined),
            title: Text('各種リンク集'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Link()),
              );
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.call_outlined),
            title: Text('各種連絡先'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Call()),
              );
            },
          ),

          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
            title: Text('設定/その他'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Setting()),
              );
            },
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are having. What information are you looking to display? Why are you unable to do so at the moment?

Comment: Updated questions. The information you want to display is the account information you registered with Auth

This includes your email address and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the fields you want to display as members of your state class:

```dart
class YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
    String? name;
    String? email;
    String? image;
    String? uid; 
    // ...
```

Then in your `initState()` method, set those values rather than create new variables:

```dart
void initState(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        // here, don't declare new variables, set the members instead
        setState(() {
            name = user.displayName; // <-- User ID
            email = user.email; // <-- Their email
            image = user.photoURL;
            uid = user.uid;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

And then when you want to display the values, you can create `Text` widgets with them:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
    Text(name ?? 'default text if name is null')
    // similar for the other values you want to diplay
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to display it, but it shows "Null", perhaps because of the time lag in retrieving it.

If I do a hot reload, it will show up again, but is there a better way?

Comment: Updated the answer to user `setState()` to update the fields. This will tell flutter to rebuild the widget with the updated values.

Comment: Thanks for the late night answer!
I was able to get it to display successfully. I seriously can't thank you enough.

I am Japanese and don't often use this site (sorry for the machine translation), but thank you for your sincere answer.

Thanks to you, I now understand the structure of getting account information.

Thank you very much for your good answer. Have a nice day!